# boot problem, desktop system not completely loaded

Tags: boot, .desktop

My Kubuntu 22.04 sometimes does not boot completely.
A text file in Auto Start loads (and strangely I can edit this auto started file) and the desktop wallpaper appears, but the taskbar does not load and I cannot do anything.
Except pressing CTRL+Del than it shuts down, or I can access my other account if I had been logged in. And this phenomenon emerge only with the admin account, not the other one I am using too.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Try reinstalling grub and see how that works, or try using a different boot loader.

Comment: I just recently reinstalled grub. Anyway I cant test it because the problem is only occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

try one of those:

1. Killing the `plasmashell` process and restarting it.
2. delete the `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` file and recreat it.
3. reinstall the `plasma-desktop`.



   **Killing the `plasmashell` process and restarting it from a terminal:**

---

To terminate the `plasmashell` process you will need access to a terminal. On most distributions you can get a terminal with <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F1</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F2</kbd>. Don't worry, your screen will turn black and you will be prompted to log in with your username and password.

**To get back to your regular KDE session you will need to press <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F7</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F1</kbd>!**

Once you have opened a terminal session you can stop the plasmashell process with

```
killall plasmashell
```

and start it again with

```
plasmashell &
```

The `&` is only required if you want to be able to close the terminal or want to be able to keep using it for other commands. It will start the plasmashell process in the background so it does not close with the terminal and does not  keep blocking the terminal from receiving further input.

Alternatively you can kill the plasmashell process in your terminal and then immediately return to KDE and hit your hotkey for krunner, which is afaik <kbd>ALT+F2</kbd> by default, and enter `plasmashell` there.

## **delete the ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc file and recreatit.**

deleted the file by (ALT-F2 "konsole"):

```
rm ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
```

Then logout from the session (ALT-F2 "logout")
Log back in, and the taskbar is now visible, some settings were lost (background color, ...)

keep a backup of the file, in case it happens again:

```
cp ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.backup
```

### **reinstall the plasma-desktop to use KDE again:**

sudo apt-get reinstall plasma-desktop

Alternatively you can use the dpkg-reconfigure to reconfig your plasma desktop:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure plasma-desktop
```

This is a problem for ***some*** kde updates.

related:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/1131728/kde-taskbar-missing/1678301#1678301
2. http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeadmin/+bug/331192/

Comment: Thanks @Talaat Etman. I assume this is meant in general so that the problem doesn't repeat. because when it doesn't boot properly I also can't open a Terminal. I think I have tried this once, a while ago.